# How to organize ember app using Controllers and Views

Tags: ember.js

What would be a good mix of Controllers, Views and other ember constructs to put together an app with the basic functionality in the wireframe below?

I'm not looking for detailed implementations but rather inspiration of how to structure Ember apps and how to reason about controllers, views, templates etc. as building blocks.

My assumption is that this screen lives under the `ContactsRoute` and that the `ContactsController` is an `ArrayController` containing `Contact` models (the selected state is only UI and not persisted).

[image: Simple contacts browser]

Comment: You're spot on. You shouldn't need anything else to construct this page. Can you be more specific? Are you unsure how to make parts of the page or what?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts as I have something similar running:

I see two layout-columns here:

**Left Col**: Is a TreeNavView with associated Controller.
It is selected if you enter #/contacts (and #/contacts/)

**Right Col**: The ContactsView with associated Controller. The view might well be assembled from smaller view atoms like the input controls etc.

Special note on controllers: In my experience, you are more or less forced in Ember to have a 1:1 relation between controller and view -- so shared controllers are a bad thing and hardly to manage.

The application view contains the HTML/ CSS layout and has two outlets for both columns.

How to render the corresponding views into the outlets?
For the left col I would directly "invoke" the view from the application view template like this:

```
{{view App.TreeNav}}
```

The "right outlet" I would fill via a corresponding router mapping:

```
this.route('contacts', {path: '/contacts'});
```

and route:

```
IB.ContactsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
          this._super();
          this.render('contacts', {into: 'application', outlet: 'secondCol'});
    }
});
```